# Certbot cannot check challenge because of Apache "Redirect / domain.com"

Tags: centos, virtualhost, redirect, apache2, certbot

So there is this server that is all messed up but that is besides the point.

I ran certbot and it failed. Checked the vhost for port 80. It has the blanket redirect.

It dose not seem like it would cause a problem right? Well it is, I commented it out and certbot ran no problem.

So then I tired creating a new vhost just for certbot. "ServerName domain.com.well-known Directory /var/www/certbot" Then running certbot specifying the new directory. No dice, It said it needs to be the root directory for the website.

I tried other things too and non of them worked. idk what to do, I do not even know if that redirect is necessary but I cannot really mess with it. If that is the only way then that is what we must do, use yearly certs and change them manually or something.

Comment: How are you running certbot? The certbot apache module should configure Apache automatically properly. All my :80 virtualhosts are just redirects, I have nothing special configured for certbot.

Comment: `ServerName domain.com.well-known` is nonsense. `.well-known` is a path inside the virtual server, not part of a virtual host name.

Comment: solution was to remove the Redirect / https.domain.com and replace it with rewrite rules with a condition to not redirect anything /.well-known

Answer (score -1):

Certbot won't issue a cert for an vhost biding port 80 only as port 80 is literally protocol non-secure http.

You need to add port 443 biding to your ready existing vhost which is https, unless you use Certbot Apache2 plugin by calling Certbot with --apache option.

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
  </VirtualHost>
```

And not sure to understand your point about redirection.
But don'g expect certbot issue cert for an redirection as certificate is associated to a hostname (url) and will also traceroute domain before issuing cert.

But if you are talking about redirect  [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to https://example.com, you could add this to your *:80 vhost.

```
Redirect / https://www.example.com/
```

And forget about well-known things and pointing out your root webdir using certbot as there's no need.
As long as the hostname you want ssl cert on it, your  vhost should also bind port *:443 parameters and are already an apache2-enabled site `a2enssite <your-site.conf / your-site.vhost>` Certbot will do the rest.

And actually i just realized, chance are, Certbot will detect your Apache2 site even without biding 443 port and will take care of do it for you, correct me if i'm wrong as been a long time not used it.

But as long as your hostname/domain/name/url call it whatever you prefer,  can be reached in browser or return ip by ping your url (outside your local network), you shouldn't have to edit nothing.

And don't forget to use Certbot --apache option. This will make the task much easier. You need to install package first (sudo apt install python3-certbot-apache) or something like that.

Comment: Your answer is simply wrong in so many areas. Please delete it.